# Is there a good tool to view a stock portfolio's value as a graph?

Tags: stocks

I'd like to view my portfolio as a graph - preferably broken down by individual stock.  What I have in mind (though of course I'm flexible):

- I enter buys and sells manually
- at any time I can view a graph of portfolio value and every stock's (and option's_ value (line graph and/or stacked bar graph maybe?)
- it's updated during the day (not necessarily in real-time - 15/20 min. delay is fine)
- must be able to hand both equities and options

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by viewing your portfolio as a graph. Most broker accounts offer some sort of reporting and statements. Do you just want to see the total value of your account as a single bar with the individual positions as chunks of the bar? Or a pie chart graph? More context please

Answer (score 4):

[**Edit in 2020**] Google Finance no longer has Portfolios feature since 2018, making this answer obsolete.

---

Google Finance will do all the bullet points in your list and a few more.  The only drawback is that you have to enter ALL buy and sell manually.  It has an import feature, but it does not work with all trading software.

http://www.google.com/finance

Let me know if it works.  Also, yahoo.com/finance has a good tool, but I still like better Google's application.

Comment: I didn't know about Google Finance's portfolios.  I like the summary graph too.  But not being able to add options to a portfolio is pretty much a deal-breaker.

Comment: Based on this recommendation I started using Finance. I've stopped now because of its limitations and bugs. Limit ex: It will automatically handled dividends but only to put them into Cash, not to reinvest. Bug ex: for the last several days I cannot save changes to transactions, nor can I import a CSV that I exported and then updated. I'm done with it until it works better.

Comment: Google Finance no longer has Portfolios feature since 2018 :-( [source](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/7579076?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if Wikivest can handle options, but I've been pretty satisfied with it as a portfolio visualization tool. It links automatically with many brokerage accounts, and has breakdowns by both portfolio and individual investment levels.